# Apple Watch indoor running error in calculating distance

Tags: apple-watch

I'm using my Apple Watch 2 for indoor running and found that in the first Kilometer Apple Watch show 750 meters and go on. The calibration I found is good for outdoors. Is it possible to adjust and calibrate the indoor distance?

Comment: Do you mean Apple Watch 2?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as calibrating WATCH Series 2 for outdoor use, since it has an onboard GPS receiver that is always active during outdoor run/walk/swim activities.

When you run outdoors, you are calibrating your WATCH Series 2 for indoor use. This requires using the default **Workout** app, with a good GPS signal (clear line of sight to the satellites), for at least 20 minutes.

For best results, [Apple recommends](https://support.apple.com/HT204516) running for at least 20 minutes, away from tall trees and buildings, preferably on flat terrain.

Repeat this process for various running paces. If you run a 12-minute mile during calibration, running a 9-minute mile indoors will yield inaccurate distance estimates.